# What package provides pgfplots.sty?

Tags: package-management, latex

I'm running into the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `pgfplots.sty' not found.
```

How should PGFPlots be installed in Ubuntu 14.04? I have installed the following packages already:

- texlive-full
- texlive-latex-extra
- texlive-bibtex-extra
- texlive-fonts-recommended
- pdflatex

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `pgfplots.sty` file should be provided by the `texlive-pictures` package on 14.04

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04 LTS"
$ 
$ dpkg -S pgfplots.sty
texlive-pictures: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.sty
$
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: For Fedora: tha package name is texlive-pgfplots . I guess the same is true for Red Hat and CentOS.